# How do I check database brand/type dynamically in Slick

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I use Oracle in production and H2 in my unit tests. Since we use Oracle Spatial I need to represent geometry objects in some way that will be different in Oracle and H2. I don't need to operate on the geometry types in the database (or at least I have no expectations to be able to do that :-) ). Therefore I'll just map geometry to a text-field in H2 so that I can suppert input/output.

I imagine mapping the geometry column like this:

```
def shape = if (<database is oracle)
    column[Geometry]("SHAPE") (geometry2SdoGeometryMapper(TmcGeometry.srid))
  else if (<database is oracle>)
    column[Geometry]("SHAPE", O.DBType("text")) (geometry2TextMapper)
  else 
    sys.error(s"Unimplemented database type $<database type>)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to abstract this `shape` method, into a higher order Slick component, that takes a type parameter, with the appropriate subtypes. Something like this could work:

```
trait DBtype {
  val GeometryMapper: {the expected type}
  val Driver: Driver
}
GeometryRepository[B <: DBType] {
  def shape = B.GeometryMapper
}
trait Oracle extends DBtype {
  override val GeometryMapper = column[Geometry]("SHAPE") (geometry2SdoGeometryMapper(TmcGeometry.srid))
  override val Driver = OracleDriver
}
```

See [this example](https://github.com/blinkboxbooks/common-slick.scala/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/blinkbox/books/slick/SlickSupport.scala) for database type parameterisation in slick.

Answer (score 0):

you could do a `driver.isInstanceOf[OracleDriver]` and `driver.isInstanceOf[H2Driver]`